# Is there an autodesk forge API available to lock files in BIM 360 or ACC?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I want to be able to lock files on Autodesk BIM360 or ACC projects. I can't find any forge API for this purpose available on the official documentation. Is there an exposed endpoint for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a good question, unfortunately, there is no endpoint to provide this feature at this moment, but I will talk to our engineering team about your request, and will let you know if any new update.

[Updated on Aug 17th]:
With the information from engineering team, this behavior could be achieved via patching "reserved" attribute of the items. For example:

curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items/:item_id' 
-X 'PATCH' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer AuIPTf4KYLTYGVnOHQ0cuolwCW2a' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json' 
-d '{
"jsonapi": {
"version": "1.0"
},
"data": {
"type": "items",
"id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:AeYgDtcTSuqYoyMweWFhhQ",
"attributes": {
"reserved": true
}
}
}'

Comment: Thanks Zhong. The file locking endpoint would be very useful for document management workflow. I hope we see one available soon.

Comment: The wish is logged as DMINFRA-1045, please feel free to check back for the status with this ID.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I updated the comments inline, please check...